# How to get path to file in winforms application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

How can I get the path of a file on my computer or on the local area network.

I would to show a window that allows me to browse the file system when I click a button, and I want to select a file and get the path to the file. How can I do this?

P.S. I'm not looking to upload the file; I just want to get the path.

Comment: If you completely change the Question (totally different technology ASP.NET -> VB.NET) you should delete the Question and Ask a new one with the correct details.

Comment: James Johnson-> it can be both of them. Mufasa-> no it is not needed to delete question, question is the same, how to get path. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web application is running on the server, and you don't have access to the client file system at all. Can you imagine how much of a vulnerability that would be? I know I don't want the sites I visit inspecting my file system...

**EDIT**: Question is for a WinForms application

For a WinForms application, you can use the `OpenFileDialog`, and extract the path with something like this:

If you're looking for the file path:

```
string path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName; //output = c:\folder\file.txt
```

If you're looking for the directory path:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName); //output = c:\folder
```

In general, the `System.IO.Path` class has a lot of useful features for retrieving and manipulating path information.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in VB.NET use the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Due to security restrictions browsers include for user safety, you can't manipulate the client file system directly. You can only use  to let them pick a file, and even then it only sends the filename, not the whole path.

The FileSystem API in HTML5 allows for file manipulation, but only within a sandbox for your site specifically, not browsing across the network or other files on the client system.

Instead, provide your users easy steps on how they should use My Computer (or whatever equivalent on other OS's) to navigate to the file and copy & paste the path into a simple text input box.

Comment: FYI: This answer applies to ASP.NET. The poster changed the question to VB.NET after I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class from [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) ?